# How Can I test my android app for multiple devices?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app... when I run it on my Motorola it runs ok, but when I launch it in my Samsung device, that has less screen size, the app doesn't show some buttons. It seems that the resolution is different in either both devices.
How can I configure my app so I don't have problems running in mostly devices?

Comment: How are you creating your screens? On Android you can have different designs for different sized (and dpi) screens. Although Android does try to scale things so you might have your axml files wrong.  Can you post either the code or axml files?

Answer (score 2):

As stated @abed in his answer, ConstraintLayout should be good for solving most of this issues, but you can never know that it will be fine on all devices.

Testing on multiple devices is one way to be sure, so if you expect that there will be problems, or that something should be different. You can easy see behavior on multiple devices inside android studio like this:

[image]

So just change phones with different resolution and observe behavior. If you want different behavior create new layout for that resolution.

Answer (score 1):

when you build your layout Use `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`
check this https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout